# Short post apocalyptic story about evil gang

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I read it in the 1980s in some unremembered book of short stories.
The tale takes place maybe a generation after nuclear war, in a cabin hidden in the backwoods of America.

A man and woman and their early teens daughter live in near starvation amid a snowy landscape, they were (I think) hippies, so that may date the story back to the late 1960s.

He’s out in the woods chopping up deadfalls for firewood and some raiders find the cabin, the woman screams and tells the girl to hide.
The man, possibly known as Mouse, comes running with the axe, she can see how afraid he is, he is outnumbered and killed.

The raiders then rape the woman and daughter and force her to cook what little food there is, they are amazed by the old fashioned stove,  in the bombed out city there are only open fires.

They have with them, on a leash, a mutant, I think he might be a brother of the rape gang leader. This unfortunate person has no eyes or arms, they throw scraps to him and he fumbles about with his toes and then flexes food to his mouth.

The gang drag her and her daughter outside, possibly to slaughter them, but arrows fly out the bushes and kill two bad guys, the others run away. Their rescuer is a wanderer from a far away valley, he invites them both to go with him and they pack to set off on the journey.

Suddenly he is killed in a return raid by the surviving gang members, then they revenge themselves on the females, they again rape them, then get the stove red hot and make them dance on it as their feet burn.

That’s all I recall of this bleak tale

Comment: Sometimes people downvote on the reason of content.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots. Yeah, I'll try and remember to only ask about happy jolly stories haha

Comment: What makes this science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not appear to be a question about science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Lexible - It's set in a post-apocalyptic future *"a generation after nuclear war"*

Comment: @Valorum Nuclear war is not science fiction: WWII in the Pacific theatre was a nuclear war, with survivors, and the generations afterward coping with their own apocalypse (I've met one survivor of such and listened to their story of the horrors of the event).

Comment: @Lexible - Indeed. But not in America, where this story is set.

Comment: @Valorum Oh, I agree that this is *fiction*, but it is not *science fiction or fantasy*.

Comment: @Lwxoble - I'd think that you would be hard pressed to define WW2 as a nuclear war (the implication of the term being an *exchange* of nuclear weapons), nor of the aftermath, no matter how unpleasant as "apocalyptic"

Comment: @Valorum I would be as easily pressed as possible: [Nuclear war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_warfare)

Comment: It was definitely set after World War 3, the American cities were radioactive ruins with mutants

Comment: IMHO, anything "post-apocalyptic" counts as SF. But I have no idea what the tile or the author of this story could be. "Bleak" it is certainly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is "The House by the Crab Apple Tree" by S.S. Johnson. Originally published in the Feb. 1964 edition of The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction with a cover by Jack Gaughan illustrating the story.

The story can be read in the Feb. 1964 edition of F&SF which is online at the Internet Archive:
https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v026n02_1964-02_PDF

Comment: Yeah, having now downloaded it I can  confirm that's the grim story I was trying to find. The man was called Weed, not Mouse but I had most of the other details correct

Comment: FWIW I've found a link to a review of this story http://reflexionesfinales.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-house-by-crab-apple-tree-review.html?m=1